# Is either Ghost Rider or Mortal Kombat's Scorpion a derivative of the other?

Tags: marvel, mortal-kombat, ghost-rider

I have noticed a couple of similarities between Scorpion and Ghost Rider:

- They died and were "reborn" with additional powers
- They can expose their skulls
- They both use chains, though Scorpion's has a harpoon at the end of it
- Flames

Is one of them derivative or are these just coincidences caused by retconning or alternate versions of the characters?

Comment: Regarding the chains and flames. Scorpion initially used a rope with a hook. Chains came later. The flames are a thematic choice, since Scorpion is essentially a color-swapped subzero, whose powers are ice-related, they decided for Scorpion to have fire powers as contrast to SubZero's ice.

Comment: can somebody tweet Ed Boon and see what he says? [tweet @noobde](https://twitter.com/noobde)

Comment: “Did the Bible invent Satan in homage to MCU’s Thor: Ragnarok Surtar, because they’re both red and have flames?”

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If there was a derivation, Scorpion would be derived from Ghost Rider. *Mortal Kombat* came out in 1992, while Ghost Rider came out in *Marvel Spotlight #5* in 1972. Ghost Rider is twenty years older.

I've found several statements on the internet that Ed Boon said that Scorpion was influenced by Ghost Rider, or even an homage, but everything I've found is second-hand.

Comment: Doesn't ed boon has a twitter handle? can't we just tweet him and see what he says? [tweet @noobde](https://twitter.com/noobde)

Comment: @Mindwin done. Hopefully he'll respond.

Comment: @topher: Any answer yet?

Comment: FYI - The Danny Ketch version of Ghost Rider - which is where the chain first showed up - was introduced in 1990, so it STILL predates Scorpion by a couple of years.

Answer (score 3):

At the very least, the Johnny Blaze version of Ghost Rider did not die. Mephisto gave him the powers directly as a literal "selling your soul to the devil" moment.

Also, for every variant of Ghost Rider, when they change forms, it isn't the host's skull that is exposed, but that of Ghost Rider.

I'd say this is more of a forced coincidence on several of these examples. As Fuzzy Boots said, Ghost Rider might have been a slight influence, but there is no direct correlation between the two characters.